# All monitors go black randomly

Tags: drivers, windows-11

At completely random intervals my computer monitors all go black for 10-15s. I have no idea why this might be. Also when every I restart my computer with the restart button the computer boots but the monitors stay black. Windows is responsive in the background. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the graphics drivers, and that solved some issues but still have these random blackouts.

Comment: What is your computer model, the display adapter, the monitors, and how are they connected? Do you do anything specific when this happens?

Comment: How are your monitors connected? Have you tried different cables?

Comment: All the monitors are connected with display port cables, the models are an lg 27 GN7 and 2 AOC 27V2G5, I have recently replaced the display port cables. It doesnt seem to matter what Im doing. For example it happened twice while looking at different websites and when I play games.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently when one monitor was set up with Freesync enabled. With Freesync disabled on both or enabled on both they were fine, but with it only enabled on a single monitor I kept getting one of the monitors disconnecting and reconnecting. Try making sure your monitors are set to the same mode.

Comment: After a clean boot I got windows up and running; however,  whenever I plug more than 1 monitor in it stays black

Comment: What graphics card is it?